# Previous values are not showing on Angular UI-Select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use this module: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

I am using multi-select option. I get values from api, and show them as options of the select box.

But it doesn't show the previous selected options, even though when I use console.log($scope.modalPrivacyGroups.selected) it shows the previous selected value initially, after a while it becomes empty!

My HTML:

```
<ui-select id="privacyUsers" multiple ng-model="modalPrivacyUsers.selected" theme="bootstrap"
                           ng-disabled="disabled"
                           style="width: 100%;">
                    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select users">
                        {{$item.full_name}}
                    </ui-select-match>
                    <ui-select-choices repeat="user in allUsers | filter:$select.search">
                        {{user.full_name + ' &lt;' + user.email+ '&gt;'}}
                    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

My Angular JS Code:

```
var CustomPrivacyCtrl = function ($scope, $modal,  $modalInstance, Auth, User, Group) {
    $scope.modalPrivacyUsers = {};
    $scope.modalPrivacyUsers.selected = [];
    $scope.modalPrivacyGroups = {};
    $scope.modalPrivacyGroups.selected = [];
    $scope.allUsers = User.query();

    $scope.modalPrivacyUsers.selected = $scope.$parent.tweet.privacyUsers;
}
```

It will great if anyone can make correct or give me a solu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your original code, since some part of your code is specific to your business model.    `[plnkr]`[1](http://plnkr.co/edit/1sDxAQ7YQB8xwDQIEi8c?p=preview)